# Create a Javascript function to simulate clicking on a href on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, hyperlink

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me on this issue.  I have a basic index.php page running a XML rotating banner. In the banner you can have html links to other pages. That all works fine. I also have a jquery Contact Form that gets hidden on load in the index.php page. To activate the form I use the following href link on the index.php page, `<a href="#contactForm">ContactForm</a>`  and works and display form perfectly.

However my issue is that I cannot get the link to from the xml rotating banner to load the contact form. If I simply put the link `<a href="#contactForm">ContactForm</a>` into it nothing happens. The Contact form does not appears.  I think it maybe because the link is inside the images.xml file and the `#contactForm` cannot get activated from within that file.  I think the form needs to be activated from the index.php file.  So what I thought I would do is create a link to a javacript script function and calls the jquery function to show the contact form.

However, I am either going about this the wrong way or I am missing something in my LoadContactForm function.  It only triggers the alerts.  I have tried so many different code snippets and I still cannot seem to get it to work. Here is the lastest version of my function that I created that is still not working. Any help and sample code would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadContactForm()
{
alert("Load Contact Form 1!");
window.location.document.getElementById('a[href="#contactForm"]').click();
return false;
alert("Load Contact Form 2!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: How is the `<a href="#contactForm">ContactForm</a>` loading the form when it isn't part of the banner?

Answer (score 1):

Luke... You about nailed it with:
 
    $("a[href="#contactForm"]").click();

I just used the following and it does work:
    $("a[href=#contactForm]").click();

Cheers!
~Ken

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getElementById` and you dont have any id. Also your script is not jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[href="#contactForm"]").click(function(){
     alert("Form clicked");
  });

  function LoadContractForm(){
    $("a[href="#contactForm"]").click();
  }
});
```

I do not understand you question fully. How is the form hidden? Via css? What triggers the survey form? Why don't you give your survey form an id that you can refer to with `$("#idname").toggle();`

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. Here is the code for the jquery contact form.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. The contact form is a juery contact form that gets hidden on the load of the index page.  To activate it or to make it appear you use the <a href="#contactForm">ContactForm</a> link on the index page. I also have added to the form a form name and tried that but it did not work.  Here is a link to the form that I am trying to use.  http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/

Comment: As T.J. Crowder pointed out, I am trying to activate the form from the banner that is running from the images.xml file. That is why I thought maybe the best approach would be to create a javascript function to show the contact form even if that function was excuted from inside the images.xml file controlling the banner. Sorry I am new to this forum. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is part of the code that hides and then shows the form: `$( init );

// Initialize the form

function init() {

  // Hide the form initially.
  // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
window.
  $('#contactForm').hide().submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' );

  // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
  // 1. Fade the content out
  // 2. Display the form

  $('a[href="#contactForm"]').click( function() {
    $('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', .2 );
    $('#contactForm').fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
      $('#senderName').focus();

Comment: Here is the Form Name and Form ID (first line of code for the form)`<form name="contactForm" form id="contactForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">
`

Comment: Here again is part of the code that hides and then shows the form: `$( init ); // Initialize the form function init() { // Hide the form initially. // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler. window. $('#contactForm').hide().submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' ); // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked: // 1. Fade the content out // 2. Display the form $('a[href="#contactForm"]').click( function() { $('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', .2 ); $('#contactForm').fadeIn( 'slow', function() { $('#senderName').focus();`

Comment: @Tom It sounds like all you need to do is to make your banner listen for an event of it being clicked. So if your banner has an id of "banner" then you should do `$("#banner").click(function(){ $("a[href="#contactForm"]").click()});`